# Error when trying to use VBO "array vertex_buffer_object must be disabled to call this method"

Tags: java, opengl, language-agnostic, jogl, vbo

**EDIT**

*I have effectively rewritten this question in order to greatly improve its quality - see revision logs if you must*

I have narrowed down my problem to the initialisation phase of my program, when I am trying to create my vertex buffer. The code that I am currently using is...

```
vaoID = new int[1];
gl.glGenVertexArrays(1, vaoID, 0);
gl.glBindVertexArray(vaoID[0]);
vboID = new int[1];
gl.glGenBuffers(1, vboID, 0);
gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID[0]);
FloatBuffer vData = FloatBuffer.allocate(vertexData.length);
vData.put(vertexData);
vData.rewind();
gl.glBufferData(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vData.capacity() * (Float.SIZE / 8), vData, GL4.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // With out this line my code throws the exception
gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, null); // This is the line where the exception is thrown
gl.glBindVertexArray(0);
```

So yes, at present my code is able to run with out crashing, but it must have a mistake some where as I am not able to get this to render. For the buffering the index data, I use this code, which does complete successfully when it runs

```
gl.glGenBuffers(1, bufferIDs, 0);
gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferIDs[0]);
ShortBuffer iData = ShortBuffer.allocate(indexData.length);
iData.put(indexData);
iData.rewind();
indexCount = iData.capacity();
gl.glBufferData(GL4.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexCount * (Short.SIZE / 8), iData, GL4.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Then when it comes to drawing, I perform the following steps, and I don't think this really matters, as I am sure I am still not buffer correctly in the first place

```
// first I bind my VAO
gl.glBindVertexArray(vaoID[0]);
// then bind, draw, unbind the index buffer
gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferIDs[0]);
gl.glDrawElements(GL4.GL_POINT, indexCount, GL4.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
// finally I unbind the VAO
gl.glBindVertexArray(0);
```

I am fairly sure that this is the correct process for rendering buffered geometry. I have confirmed that my shader code is correct and valid by use of some immediate drawing commands, so I do I have full pipeline, it just seems I am not feeding data into it. As a point of interest, I also tried editing my vertex shader to set all points to (0,0,0,1) so that if any points where being passed in, I should see them, but this did not work, which I took to mean that I am not passing data into my shader in the first place.

Comment: Is your init code posted in its entirety? You seem to be glDisabling stuff without ever glEnabling it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`glVertexAttribPointer` has two modes of operation. If there's no VBO bound, it takes a pointer to the data as the last argument. If there's a VBO bound the last argument is instead an integer offset into the buffer. In C, you have to cast this integer into a pointer anyway, but it is not treated as a pointer if there's a VBO bound.

In JOGL, these two modes are realized with two overloads: [one that takes a `Buffer`](http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/jogl/docs/javax/media/opengl/GL.html#glVertexAttribPointer%28int,%20int,%20int,%20boolean,%20int,%20java.nio.Buffer%29) (instead of a pointer) and [one that takes a `long`](http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/jogl/docs/javax/media/opengl/GL.html#glVertexAttribPointer%28int,%20int,%20int,%20boolean,%20int,%20long%29) (instead of an offset cast into a pointer).

If you use the first one with a VBO bound it throws an error because that's the mode that only works without a VBO bound. If you unbind your VBO and pass `null` to the last parameter, you're still calling the first overload: `null` can match a `Buffer` parameter, but not a `long`. JOGL seems to not have a similar validation for this case. This will probably treat it as the offset 0, but it will also store 0 as the VBO to look for the data. That is, no VBO at all.

What you need to do is, using your original code, i.e., with a VBO bound, call the overload that takes an offset instead:

```
//pass a long instead of a null Buffer
gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0L);
```

And there is also another issue that is not letting anything render. You're passing `GL4.GL_POINT` to `glDrawElements`. That's not a valid assembly mode. I don't know what it is for (my OpenGL 4 knowledge fails me). The constant for the points assembly mode is named `GL_POINTS`:

```
gl.glDrawElements(GL.GL_POINTS, indexCount, GL4.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

Comment: AFAIR `glVertexAttribPointer` requires VBO to be bound only when the last argument is not null. But it does sound like a bug nevertheless.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus You're right that it doesn't require one to be bound! I completely forgot about that. The last argument is either 1) a pointer to the data, if no VBO is bound, or 2) an offset, (ridiculously cast into a pointer) if a VBO is bound. This got me thinking how you would cast a random integer into a "pointer" in Java and led to spelunking in the very crappy JOGL docs. Thanks for triggering this discovery!

Comment: This did eventually work, though it took a lot of work from Martin in chat to help me out with other things. mainly, GL_POINTS not GL_POINT

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your VBO is still bound when you go to do the VA draw. Make sure that whenever you use glBindBuffer to bind a VBO for a draw call, then after you've done the draw, bind the ARRAY/ELEMENT_ARRAY buffer back to 0. Also make sure to disable any client states or attrib arrays that you enable after you've done the draw.

```
// vbo draw
gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferID[0]);
gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, null); // I know that this should be changed, but can't get code to run to this as can't buffer data in first place
gl.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

// ibo draw
gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferIDs[0]);
gl.glDrawElements(GL4.GL_POINT, indexCount, GL4.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

You might also have to do these in the initialize method(s) as well (disable everything you enable after you're done generating stuff, and bind stuff back to zero after you've passed the data). Otherwise, when it gets to draw the VA, then the VBO stuff is enabled so GL gets confused because it thinks it has to do something with the VBO because it's enabled but really you just want to use the VA.

This is my best guess to your problem. Feel free to comment on my post if it didn't solve it.

Comment: sorry if this seems ignorant, but you have suggested a change to the draw code, but it is the code that is initially buffering my vertex data that is throwing an error. Also, I thought that if I where to use VAO, when I draw, I only need to bind that VAO, and the VBO and associated atrtrib pointers are restored.

Comment: My answer does apply to the initialize method. Try binding vertex array to 0 before you start using the vbo: `glBindVertexArray(0);` (right before `vboID = new int[1];`)

Comment: I think I found that I can only call `glVertexAttribPointer` after I call `gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);` updated the question to reflect my findings... but not sure what to do with it now :S

Comment: I don't really understand why you're calling glVertexAttribPointer in your initialize code. That's draw code, isn't it?

Comment: @arasmussen It would belong to the initialization code if he used the VAO correctly, in which case he should just call `glBindVertexArray` in the draw method and nothing else. But at the moment his VAO is just useless.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this one?
Just a guess though

```
vaoID = new int[2];
gl.glGenVertexArrays(1, vaoID[0], 0);
gl.glBindVertexArray(vaoID[0]);
gl.glGenBuffers(1, vboID[1], 0);
gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID[1]);
FloatBuffer vData = FloatBuffer.allocate(vertexData.length);
vData.put(vertexData);
vData.position(0);
gl.glBufferData(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vData.capacity() * (Float.SIZE / 8), vData, GL4.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
gl.glBindBuffer(GL4.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // With out this line my code throws the exception
gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, null); // This is the line where the exception is thrown
gl.glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Comment: I see what you are thinking... but functions like `glGenVertexArray` take an `int[]` not just an `int`. I did try using `position(0)` rather then `rewind()` but it made no difference.